# sencha - sort store by multi fields

Tags: list, sorting, model, sencha-touch

I have a model which contains some fields.

now I need to sort the store by 2 of the fields (e.g. type,first name)

How can I to it with sencha?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

simple just try this

```
store.sort("name", "DESC");


store.sort("name", "ASC");
```